# Unable to connect to mongodb, ssl error, timeout errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, ssl, certificate

I am trying to connect to my cloud mongodb database using pymongo. When I try to run a basic insert, I run into issues with ssl certificate error.

Ive tried setting the ssl=False but this just resulted in a ServerSelectionTimeoutError. Ive tried running the code on other people's computers and it runs perfectly fine and inserts correctly.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://thejordanchoi:sasha@testcluster-0rbdo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", ssl=False)

db = client['testdatabase']

collection = db['testcollection']

testdata = {
    'name' : 'ethan',
    'age' : 20
}

test_data_id = collection.insert_one(testdata).inserted_id
print(test_data_id)

print('eof')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while making a connection on mac. Followed the below mentioned steps to resolve that:

1. Execute below mentioned command. It basically remove existing file or link and create symlink to certifi certificate bundle

   /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
2. Add your IP Address to IP Whitelist in atlas.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you get `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,ip not in whitelist,ip not in whitelist` error then add your IP Address to IP Whitelist in atlas.

[image]

2) Don't use `ssl=False` parameter. This is causing the `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed` error.

After removing the `ssl=False` parameter, if you get the error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.` then follow step 2.

2) make sure the user `thejordanchoi` has write access to the `testdatabase`.

With the above two changes, I was able to write successfully with your code snippet.

Comment: 1) I've never actually got the ip not in whitelist error

Comment: Then try from step 2

Comment: 2i) after taking out ssl=False I get this:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: testcluster-shard-00-01-0rbdo.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056),testcluster-shard-00-00-0rbdo.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056),testcluster-shard-00-02-0rbdo.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Comment: 2ii) User thejordanchoi has access to the testdatabase.
I'm thinking its something wrong with my local machine since it works fine on other machines. Maybe some sort of SSL issue? I don't know too much about ssl so I'm not sure where to start in debugging

Comment: I also tried checking my ssl ceritifcate and got:
MacBook-Pro:test thejordanchoi$ openssl verify cert.pem
Error opening certificate file cert.pem
4696172140:error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.240.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:255:fopen('cert.pem', 'r')
4696172140:error:20FFF002:BIO routines:CRYPTO_internal:system lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.240.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:257:
unable to load certificate

Comment: okay so i got it to work, after updating ceritifi and pymongo. thanks ofr the help though!

Answer (score -1):

> MongoDB [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')

This error is specially for Mac users, because the client ID of mongoDB is different for Mac and Windows.

```py
clientMAC = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://**namehere**:**namehere**@cluster0.0osjv.mongodb.net/<dbname>?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE')
db = clientMAC.get_database('**databasename**')
```

Use the above Client ID on Mac, edit only bold words (namehere & databasename) and should not show ssl error